# Parsing malformed JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to parse [this content](http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/scorestrip.json) using Javascript. The data looks like this:

`{"ss":[["Thu","7:00","Final",,"BAL","19","ATL","20",,,"56808",,"PRE4","2015"],["Thu","7:00","Final",,"NO","10","GB","38",,,"56809",,"PRE4","2015"]]}`

Every single tutorial online teaches you how to parse JSON using Twitter, but I am not quite sure how parsing with JSON works.

I would like to set this up on a website to view the NFL team scores for a fun project and a good learning experience about parsing JSON, as I could care less about Twitter stuff.

Is this possible? Any good tutorials to start with? Even some starting code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can use [JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html) to do this.  However, that snippet that you have does not appear to be strictly valid JSON (as seen here:  http://jsfiddle.net/yK3Gf/ and also by validating the source JSON here:  http://jsonlint.com/).

So you will either need to parse it by hand, or get nfl.com to fix up their JSON.

As an alternative, their JSON does parse successfully when using `eval()`, so you could parse it with something like:

```
var parsedData = eval('(' + jsonData + ')');
```

...as shown here:  http://jsfiddle.net/yK3Gf/1/

Though be aware that parsing JSON in this way is generally frowned upon (particularly when the data being parsed is being delivered by a third-party source), as it leaves you open to XSS attacks should the data happen to include any executable code inside of it.

Comment: You can use [Crockford's eval guard](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/ad6079cbd8dc362a3cc42e1f97c01aa5ccd48bfe/json2.js#L456) to prevent script execution. I always do.

Comment: Awesome advice I am going to utilize this approach for now as I am learning.

Answer (score 3):

I am in a similar position - non javascript expert working on a fun project to familiarize myself with javascript, ajax, and json.

I took three different steps to handle the problem. I welcome any feedback on improving the solution.

The first step is to query the nfl site to pull down the scores. Because the source of the json, the nfl site, is different from your site, you will have to work around the javascript security constraints against cross domain querying.  I found this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) to be a good reference.  I used JSONP for the workaround.  I used http://whateverorigin.org/ as the indirection site.

```
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/scorestrip.json') + '&callback=?', handleQueryForScoresResult);
```

As others have pointed out, the nfl site returns invalid json data.  The following sample line illustrates the problem:

> ["Sun","4:25","Final",,"TEN","7","MIN","30",,,"55571",,"REG5","2012"],

Notice the empty array element values (the repeated commas with no data in between).  So in my json callback function, I corrected the data by adding empty strings (two double quotes) to repeated commas before calling jquery to parse the json data:

```
function handleQueryForScoresResult(data) {
    var jsonStr = data.contents;
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(/,,/g, ',"",');
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(/,,/g, ',"",');

    var scoresData = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonStr).ss;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Lastly, I created GameScores object to encapsulate the json data.

```
function GameScore(scoreData) {
    this.scoreData = scoreData;
    scoreData[2] = scoreData[2].toLowerCase();
    scoreData[5] = parseInt(scoreData[5]);
    scoreData[7] = parseInt(scoreData[7]);
} 

function GameScore_getAwayTeam() { return this.scoreData[4]; }
function GameScore_getHomeTeam() { return this.scoreData[6]; } 
function GameScore_isFinal() { return this.scoreData[2]=="final"; }  
function GameScore_getHomeTeamScore() { return this.scoreData[7]; }
function GameScore_getAwayTeamScore() { return this.scoreData[5]; }
function GameScore_doesHomeTeamLead() { return this.scoreData[7]> this.scoreData[5]; }
function GameScore_doesAwayTeamLead() { return this.scoreData[5]> this.scoreData[7]; }
function GameScore_getWeekId() { return this.scoreData[12]; }

GameScore.prototype.getHomeTeam = GameScore_getHomeTeam;
GameScore.prototype.getAwayTeam = GameScore_getAwayTeam;
GameScore.prototype.isFinal = GameScore_isFinal;
GameScore.prototype.getHomeTeamScore = GameScore_getHomeTeamScore;
GameScore.prototype.getAwayTeamScore = GameScore_getAwayTeamScore;
GameScore.prototype.doesHomeTeamLead = GameScore_doesHomeTeamLead;
GameScore.prototype.doesAwayTeamLead = GameScore_doesAwayTeamLead;
GameScore.prototype.getWeekId = GameScore_getWeekId;
```

I only added a few accessors as I did not need most of the data.  Your needs may vary.

Comment: Thanks so much for the dirty JSON cleanup help... this NFL API has been killing me. Mucho Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

We are using [mootools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/JSON) for stuff like that, but you can do it it plain JavaScript as well: http://www.json.org/js.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that fact that the JSON your pulling in is malformed or not valid according to RFC 4627.

What you can do is grab the copy the JSON data and format it using this tool http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html

After you have the formatted version then you can use the jQuery ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your-formatted.json",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.ss.length; i++) {
            document.write("Day: " + data.ss[i][0]);
            document.write("<br/>");
            document.write("Time: " + data.ss[i][1]);
            document.write("<br/><br/>");
        }
    }
});
```

You shouldn't actually use document.write in your application. This is only for example purpose of displaying the data.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you already have a valid JSON `String` (`jsonString`) to parse. (If you don't know how to retrieve a `String` to parse using `XMLHttpRequest` from the given url you will have to look into that first.)

---

With plain JavaScript you will have to add Douglas Crockford's JSON library (or something similar) in order to provide a parsing `Function` if there is no native implementation:

```
var json = json_parse(jsonString) ;
```

- [link](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js)

---

With a JavaScript library like *jQuery* this would be

```
var json = $.parseJSON(jsonString) ;
```

---

Now, traversing the resultant JSON `Object` is a whole other issue, because you will have to know its structure before you can retrieve specific data. 
In this particular case -- if it was indeed well formed -- you would have to do the following:

```
var data = json.ss ;

     for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {

          var entry = data[i] ;

          var day = entry[0] ; //!! the Arrays seem to have a format where the first entry always contains the data and so forth...
          /* ... */

          // then do something with the data bits

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific issue (the empty indexes within the arrays from the JSON response) I did a regex replacement with a lookahead assertion. Considering that request contains the `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
request.responseText.replace(/,(?=,)/gm, ",\"\"")
```

This will turn `,,` into `,"",` and will also work in case there are more commas in sequence, so `,,,` becomes `,"","",`. You can use `JSON.parse()` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This malformed JSON can be parsed by the [dirty-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dirty-json) NPM package (I am the author).

You can test a demo of the parser here: https://rmarcus.info/dirty-json

The parser interprets the JSON in your original question as equivalent to the following valid JSON:

```
{
    "ss": [
        [
            "Thu",
            "7:00",
            "Final",
            "BAL",
            "19",
            "ATL",
            "20",
            "56808",
            "PRE4",
            "2015"
        ],
        [
            "Thu",
            "7:00",
            "Final",
            "NO",
            "10",
            "GB",
            "38",
            "56809",
            "PRE4",
            "2015"
        ]
    ]
}
```