# Parsing json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing JSON with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886935/parsing-json-with-javascript)

I understand to get the value of a json data, for instance `var json = [{"country":"US"}]`, I can do it like `json[0].country`.

I've this json data `[{"0":"US"}]`, so how do I retrieve the data then?

Comment: As a side note, properties in general an be accessed with array notation. Even with an object `var myvar = { mykey: myvalue }` you can do `myvar[mykey]`. You can event execute functions `var myvar = { mykey: function(){...} }` with `myvar[mykey]()`.

Comment: @Didier G.: You mean `myvar["mykey"]`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet. Indeed! Sorry for the typoh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `json[0]['0']` as the "0" is just a name as far as JavaScript is concerned

Comment: Note that `json[0][0]` (notice lack of quotes) will also work. The bracket notation converts everything in the brackets to a string, so `0` will be turned to `'0'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
json[0]["0"]
```

Not really much more to add to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = [{"0":"US"}];
console.log(foo[0]["0"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you'll retrieve with

```
 json[0]["0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

you may acess the value with:

```
var json = [{"0":"US"}]
json[0]["0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the key of the only object into the array is string so you can access it with:

```
var bar = [{"0":"US"}];
console.log(bar[0]['0']); // 'US'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it would just be

```
json[0]["0"]
```

to retrieve your data. The zero is in quotes the second time round, because it's stored as a string in your example.